# ServiceStack overriding Cache-Control private

Tags: servicestack, cache-control

There's some similar old questions to this, one answered and one unanswered.  The answered applies to ServiceStack 3, and the accepted answer does not work for me in 4.0.36

I can create custom response headers with the ResponseFilters, but it's not possible to override Cache-Control - it is always set to private.

```
public class NoCacheAttribute : ResponseFilterAttribute
{
    public override void Execute(IRequest req, IResponse res, object responseDto)
   {
       res.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");  //does not work
       res.AddHeader("Test", "no-store");  //works

   }
}
```

Likewise, I've also tried to set in the Service implementation itself, using the following, which again only works for custom header.  I've used the CacheControl constant and "Cache-Control" string in both methods, makes no difference:

```
Response.AddHeader(HttpHeaders.CacheControl, "no-store"); //doesn't work
Response.AddHeader("Test2", "no-store");  //works
```

Has anyone successfully done this in ServiceStack recently? It seems like some lower level ASP.NET function is keeping the Cache-Control set to "private"

Comment: Is IIS configured to set that header?  There's usually one header pre-defined in an IIS website ("X-Powered-By"), but perhaps the cache-control header is hard-coded in there?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have in v4.
I don't recall why I had to switch from `ResponseFilter` to `RequestFilter`, but I think it had to do with certain cases ending the request early and the `ResponseFilter` was skipped.

The `RequestFilter` makes sure you get the headers onto the `IResponse` object as soon as possible.

```
public class NoCacheAttribute : RequestFilterAttribute
{
    public override void Execute(IRequest req, IResponse res, object requestDto)
    {
        res.AddHeader(HttpHeaders.CacheControl, "no-store,must-revalidate,no-cache,max-age=0");
    }
}
```